# Constant vector in changing basis

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, vectors

If the unit vectors in the cylindrical coordinate system are functions of position, then how can I get a constant vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the coordinate components of the vector depend on position in a way that cancels out the dependence of the basis. For example, [one has, in cylindrical coordinates,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates#Unit_vector_conversions)
$$\hat{x} = \cos\phi \hat{r} - \sin\phi \mathbf{\hat{\phi}} \quad \text{and} \quad \hat{y} = \sin\phi \hat{r} + \cos\phi \mathbf{\hat{\phi}}.$$
The sine and cosines compensate for the position-dependency of the basis.